# how to write mysql create table query in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

how to create table query in c# for mysql database..

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=demo_test;UID=root;Password= ");

MySqlCommand acmd = new MySqlCommand("CREATE TABLE first (" + a.Columns[0] + " int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment,'" + a.Columns[1].ToString() + "' varchar(100) NOT NULL default,PRIMARY KEY (" + a.Columns[0]+") 1", con); 
con.Open();

acmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it gives me an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''name' varchar(100) NOT NULL default,PRIMARY KEY (id) 1' at line
>   1

Comment: remove single quote for  a.Columns[1]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fighting with SQL directly, you could use [Mig#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MigSharp/) like this:

```
        var schema = new DbSchema(ConnectionString, DbPlatform.MySql5);
        schema.Alter(db => db.CreateTable("first")
            .WithPrimaryKeyColumn(a.Colunns[0], DbType.Int32).AsIdentity()
            ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are wrapping the column names with single quote which converts the value into string and not an identifier anymore. Remove the single quotes and it will work.

```
string query = @"CREATE TABLE first (" + a.Columns[0] + " int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment, " 
                     + a.Columns[1].ToString() + " varchar(100) NOT NULL default,
                     PRIMARY KEY (" + a.Columns[0]+")"
```

Comment: string query = @"CREATE TABLE first (" + a.Columns[0] + " int(20) NOT NULL auto_increment, "+ a.Columns[1].ToString() + " varchar(100) NOT NULL default,PRIMARY KEY (" + a.Columns[0]+")";
            MySqlCommand acmd=new MySqlCommand();
            acmd.CommandText=query;
            acmd.Connection=con;  
              
            acmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();